# What does the type option in the hibernate console wizard do?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-tools

Hibernate tools has a Hibernate Console wizard, and it has a type option with three possible values to select from: core, annotations and jpa. 
The official documentation says nothing about the outcomes of selecting any one of these values.

What difference does it make if I choose Annotations here? I've been looking all over the docs and neither docs nor Google queries returned anything that helps. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the **"Type"** option will tell how you are going to use Hibernate with in your code. For example:

- If you select **"Core"** that means your project will contains Java Files with mappings define in XML files.
- And if you select **"Annotation"** it means you will map the properties directly in the classes using annotations.

For differences between Annotation and JPA Annotation I have found the following link first up: http://www.coderanch.com/t/422576/ORM/java/difference-between-jpa-Annotations-Hibernate

Comment: Thanks. So what does this change further in the workflow of using hibernate tools? It does not effect code generation, for that has its own settings. What does this setting change? It has not been documented anywhere I can see? I know the difference between the options, I just can't understand how this makes a difference during use of hibernate tools